# Métodos dentro de clases Java

Tags: java

Tengo que implementar una aplicación en java que permita manejar la información de un sistema Clientes y de cuentas bancarias.

De una cuenta Bancaria se conoce el Cliente, el Número de Cuenta saldo y los intereses.
Un Cliente es, a su vez, un objeto del que se conoce documento de identidad, Nombre, Teléfono y salario.

La aplicación debe permitir:
• Crear Cuentas
• Consultar el saldo de una cuenta dado el documento de un cliente
• Consignar en la cuenta, dado el número de cuenta
• Debitar en la cuenta dado el número de la cuenta.

El problema de esto es que creo dos clases CuentaBancaria y Cliente, dentro de Cliente quise crear un método llamado crearCliente que reciba todos los datos de un usuario, esto lo hice para solo llamar el método en el **main** " para luego guardarlo en un arreglo de tipo CuentaBancaria.

El caso es que me dice que **no reconoce el método**.

Código:

//CLASE CLIENTE

```
public class Cliente {

    String identidad;
    String nombre;
    String telefono;
    double salario;

    public Cliente(String identidad, String nombre, String telefono, double salario){

        this.identidad = identidad;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.salario = salario;
    }

    public String getIdentidad() {
        return identidad;
    }

    public void setIdentidad(String identidad) {
        this.identidad = identidad;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public double getSalario() {
        return salario;
    }

    public void setSalario(double salario) {
        this.salario = salario;
    }

    public static void crearCliente(){

        Cliente arreglo[] = new Cliente[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++){

            String identidad = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese su identidad: ");
            String nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese su nombre: ");
            String telefono = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese su telefono: ");
            double salario = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese su salario: "));

            arreglo[i] = new Cliente(identidad,nombre,telefono,salario);
        }

    }



}
```

//CLASE CUENTABANCARIA

```
public class CuentaBancaria {
    Cliente cliente;
    String numeroCuenta;
    double saldo;
    final double intereses = 0.04;

    public CuentaBancaria(Cliente cliente, String numeroCuenta, double saldo){

        this.cliente = cliente;
        this.numeroCuenta = numeroCuenta;
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public String getNumeroCuenta() {
        return numeroCuenta;
    }

    public void setNumeroCuenta(String numeroCuenta) {
        this.numeroCuenta = numeroCuenta;
    }

    public double getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    public void setSaldo(double saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }



    public double crearSaldo(double intereses, double salario){

        saldo = (salario*intereses)-salario;
        return saldo;

    }



}
```

Comment: Compártenos el código por favor.

Comment: Listo, ya lo agregue

Comment: El código que aportas no deja de ser básicamente lo que cualquier IDE te hace gratis. Tus preguntas debes referirse a problemas concretos antes que simplemente pedir que le hagan la tarea completa. lo mejor sería que hicieras el [tour] para saber cómo funciona el sitio.

Comment: Por curiosidad: ¿Cómo estás llamando al método `crearCliente()` desde el `main`? ¿Lo llamas como un método de clase o de instancia?

Answer (score 0):

Bueno para empezar deberías crear dos clases: Una llamada Cliente y otra llamada CuentaBancaria.
Dentro de la clase cliente, para crear un cliente debes usar un constructor esto se hace de la siguiente forma (teniendo la clase cliente):

```
public class Cliente{

    private String documentoIdentidad;

    private String nombre;

    private int telefono;

    private double salario;

    public Cliente(String documentoIdentidad, String nombre, int telefono, double salario){ //Esto es el constructor
        this.documentoIdentidad=documentoIdentidad;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.salario = salario;
    }
}
```

Ahora en la clase CuentaBancaria:

```
public class CuentaBancaria{

    private Cliente cliente;

    private String numeroCuenta;

    private double saldo;

    private int intereses;

    public CuentaBancaria(){ // Suponemos que no pasamos ningún valor al crearlo
        String nombre = "Nombre del cliente";
        String documentoIdentidad = "25987464";
        String telefono= 69874562;
        String salario = 1025.85;
        cliente = new Cliente(documentoIdentidad,nombre,telefono,salario);
        numeroCuenta = "1245678-9458754";
        saldo= 3652,54;
        intereses= 9857;
    }

}
```

Con eso tendrías creado el cliente dentro del numero de cuenta, si necesitas usarlo fuera podrías usar métodos get para obtener los datos.
Faltaría hacer el menú. Si no entiendes algo hazmelo saber.

Comment: escribí antes de que pusieses el código xD

Comment: Gracias por tu colaboración, una pregunta, dentro del constructor de CuentaBancaria no habría necesidad de colocar this.?

Comment: @CamiloJc solamente tienes que diferenciar variables con `this.variable` si usas una variable local con el mismo nombre que un campo de tu clase.

Comment: Se te aclaró la duda?

Answer (score 0):

me parece que el problema es que el método crearCliente() que has creado es estático y no puede acceder a las propiedades de la misma clase. Con borrar el static te debería valer:

```
public void crearCliente(){

        Cliente arreglo[] = new Cliente[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++){

            String identidad = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese su identidad: ");
            String nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese su nombre: ");
            String telefono = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese su telefono: ");
            double salario = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese su salario: "));

            arreglo[i] = new Cliente(identidad,nombre,telefono,salario);
        }

    }
```